# when use www in my url getting 403 error in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, url-rewriting, no-www

I have a website on vps and set https on it. but when users open site with www,
get error 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I want when users open [www.tavanyar.ir](http://www.tavanyar.ir) website goes redirect to https://tavanyar.ir

please help me to set my web.config

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

[read more about that](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/)